# ksoftirqd hitting 100% on interface with ixgbe driver

Tags: linux-networking, high-load

This is my driver information.

```
ethtool -i ethXX
driver: ixgbe
version: 3.9.15-NAPI
firmware-version: 0x800000a5
bus-info: 0000:04:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
```

Now I have an average traffic of 1/1.5 Gbps (75k packets per second) hitting this interface and I can see one/or more of the ksoftirqd threads going to 100%.

I tried enabling the rx-usecs/rx-frames option, but no improvement. A bit of latency is not an issue for me. I just want the ksoftirqd usage to go down.

I see the limit of rx-usecs is 1022, which is the usecs after which the next interrupt should be fired (thats my understanding, please correct me if I am wrong). Though it doesn't solve my problem.

rx-frames on other hand are not supported on this driver. Neither is there any support for "adaptive-rx".

What should be the next step I should be looking at? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What CPU do you have? And what version of `irqbalance` are you running?

Comment: @ David Its a 24 core machine. sample output from /proc/cpuinfo. processor : 23
vendor_id : GenuineIntel
cpu family : 6
model  : 44
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           L5638  @ 2.00GHz
I don't use irqbalance. Instead I have RSS enabled which distributes packets on 24 rx-queues and these queues are mapped to different cpus.

Comment: What are you using to map the queues to CPUs? (Also, I think your hardware only supports 4 queues.)

Comment: Each of these rx-queues (eth-TxRx-0/1/..) have one irq line assigned to them (62/63/64/...). I am editing the smp_affinity bit map in /proc/irq/<irq_no>/smp_affinity which maps one queue to one cpu. I can see 24 eth-TXRX queues.

Comment: Have you tried the newest drivers from Intel's site?  I find them to solve a lot of problems, the drivers that come with distros tend to lag behind quite a bit, which causes issues with newer hardware.

Comment: I tried with the latest ixgbe driver (3.10.16) and ethtool (3.5) , but still rx-frames and adaptive-rx are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on `rx-flow-hash` if not already turned on for `tcp4`/`udp4`/`tcp6`/`udp6` e.g.

```
ethtool -N ethX rx-flow-hash udp4 sdfn
```